How can I position my modal popup to be above my text?
I am not sure why my  tag (.btn) is appearing above my modal on popup. I have tried z-index but its not working even though position is relative. Please see my code below. I have 4 boxes when you click on the word the modal pops up. You can see that the text is showing above my modal (shown in the red blocks)


Here is my code:


.lightbox-window {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.95);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  &>div {
    width: 430px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
  }
}

.lightbox-close {
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px;
  width: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-radius: 3em;
  background: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: .1em .9em;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #F31780;
  }
}

.btn {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 47px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-width: 0px !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  padding: 0.96rem 8.29rem;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
}

.image img {
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.party {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<div class="party">
  <a class="btn" href="#open-lightbox">PARTY</a>

  <div id="open-lightbox" class="lightbox-window">
    <div class="lightbox">
      <span class="image">
              <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/64fc2b1002c42359825bbc03/t/66ae1f204ee13330597a3dcc/1722687270723/Untitled-3.png"/></span>
      <a href="#void" title="Close" class="lightbox-close">X</a>
      <h3>PARTY</h3>
      <div class="paragraph">Enjoy the best party scenes Africa has to offer. Everything from unforgettable night outs, to the hottest boozy brunches, Kampala has it all.</div>
      <a class="btn2" href="https://www.oliwatravel.com/book-now">BOOK NOW</a>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




z-index should be applied when it has the focus, else each box has the same  z-index and only the last one will show on top of the others

from my comment

z-index should be applied when it has the focus, else each box has the same  z-index and only the last one will show on top of the others

here is a snippet trying to reproduce your issue while i believe your party box have a block formatting context introducing your issue :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flow_layout/Introduction_to_formatting_contexts


.lightbox-window {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.95);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    z-index:1;
  }
  &>div {
    width: 430px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
  }
}

.lightbox-close {
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px;
  width: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-radius: 3em;
  background: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: .1em .9em;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #F31780;
  }
}

.btn {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 47px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-width: 0px !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  padding: 0.96rem 8.29rem;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
}

.image img {
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.party {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* trigger z-index only on focused part */

/*demo */
body {
background:#aaa;
display:flex;
gap:1em;
}
.party {
aspect-ratio:1;
min-width:150px;
flex:1 1 auto;
background:green;
display:grid;
place-content:center;
}
<div class="party">
  <a class="btn" href="#open-lightbox">PARTY</a>

  <div id="open-lightbox" class="lightbox-window">
    <div class="lightbox">
      <span class="image">
              <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/64fc2b1002c42359825bbc03/t/66ae1f204ee13330597a3dcc/1722687270723/Untitled-3.png"/></span>
      <a href="#void" title="Close" class="lightbox-close">X</a>
      <h3>PARTY</h3>
      <div class="paragraph">Enjoy the best party scenes Africa has to offer. Everything from unforgettable night outs, to the hottest boozy brunches, Kampala has it all.</div>
      <a class="btn2" href="https://www.oliwatravel.com/book-now">BOOK NOW</a>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="party">
  <a class="btn" href="#open-lightbox2">PARTY 2</a>

  <div id="open-lightbox2" class="lightbox-window">
    <div class="lightbox">
      <span class="image">
              <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/64fc2b1002c42359825bbc03/t/66ae1f204ee13330597a3dcc/1722687270723/Untitled-3.png"/></span>
      <a href="#void" title="Close" class="lightbox-close">X</a>
      <h3>PARTY</h3>
      <div class="paragraph">Enjoy the best party scenes Africa has to offer. Everything from unforgettable night outs, to the hottest boozy brunches, Kampala has it all.</div>
      <a class="btn2" href="https://www.oliwatravel.com/book-now">BOOK NOW</a>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="party">
  <a class="btn" href="#open-lightbox3">PARTY 3</a>

  <div id="open-lightbox3" class="lightbox-window">
    <div class="lightbox">
      <span class="image">
              <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/64fc2b1002c42359825bbc03/t/66ae1f204ee13330597a3dcc/1722687270723/Untitled-3.png"/></span>
      <a href="#void" title="Close" class="lightbox-close">X</a>
      <h3>PARTY</h3>
      <div class="paragraph">Enjoy the best party scenes Africa has to offer. Everything from unforgettable night outs, to the hottest boozy brunches, Kampala has it all.</div>
      <a class="btn2" href="https://www.oliwatravel.com/book-now">BOOK NOW</a>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



The snippet triggers a higher z-index on the .partybox which has an element .lighbox-windowreceiving the focus.

Hi there, thanks so much for your detailed reply. Unfortunately its still not working for me. It still does the same thing even in your example it does the same thing with the words infront of the popup. when you click run code snippet without making it full page, and click on party 1 you'll see it does the same thing it does for me on my page. I just cant figure out why this is happening.

@jessica, oups, my example used :focus, not :target  ... let's do it again . So you need to get that z-index higher only when targeted. .lightbox-window {   z-index:999;   &:target {     z-index:1000;   }  snippet updated

@Jessica Hello, your .fe-block also have a z-index that comes in the way, you can probably remove/overwrite them with  #siteWrapper .fe-block {   z-index:auto }

thanks so so much for your help. It worked!
